# Create New Folder Based on Cell Name and Copy Files into it

Tags: excel, vba, directory, copy

I would like to create new folder based on cell value in a sheet (Sheet3 (Cover Page) Cell B4) and with this new folder, I would like to copy multiple documents from the list (Sheet 4 Cell B5:B30) from source folder into created folder. The document list is with extension (.pdf, .docx, etc). In addition, I also would like to prevent to create folder with same name.

At this moment, I can make new folder based on cell and also can copy document in the list, but don't know how combine this two things.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
'This code is for create new folder based on cell value
Sub makenewfolder()
Dim startPath As String
Dim myName As String
startPath = "H:\Users\"
myName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cover Page").Range("B4").Text      
If myName = vbNullString Then myName = "Testing"
Dim folderPathWithName As String
folderPathWithName = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName
If Dir(folderPathWithName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MkDir folderPathWithName
Else
   MsgBox "Folder already exists"
   Exit Sub
End If
End Sub

'This code for copy files from the document list
Sub copyfiles()

Const sourcePath As String = "C:\Users\"
Const DestPath As String = "H:\User\"
Const ListAddress As String = "B5:B30"

' Write file list to array.
Dim FileList As Variant: FileList = Sheet4.Range(ListAddress).Value

' 'Get' first file name.
Dim FName As String: FName = Dir(sourcePath)
' 'Initiate' counter.
Dim i As Long
' Loop files in SourcePath.
Do While FName <> ""
    ' Check if file name of current file is contained in array (FileList).
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(FName, FileList, 0)) Then
        ' Count file.
        i = i + 1
        ' Copy file.
        FileCopy sourcePath & FName, DestPath & FName
    End If
    ' 'Get' next file name.
    FName = Dir()
Loop

' Inform user.
Select Case i
    Case 0: MsgBox "No files found", vbExclamation, "No Files"
    Case 1: MsgBox "Copied 1 file.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Case Else: MsgBox "Copied " & i & " files.", vbInformation, "Success"
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Like a main method that calls both methods sequentially?

Comment: @Christov yes. kind of like that

Comment: Try a sub with the lines
Call makenewfolder()
Call copyfiles()

Comment: It just create new folder and not copy folder into created folder